# Trying to print message in my unordered list box jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a guessing game and for some reason my text for each guesses don't show up. Can someone point in the right direction?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
       <section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

            <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

            <form>
                <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
                <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
            </form>

            <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

            <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

            </ul>

        </section>
```

JS:

```
$("#guessButton").click(function(){
        var guess = $('#userGuess').val;
        if (guess == number) {
            $('#guessList').text("<li>You've guessed the number!!</li>");
        } else if (guess < number) {
            $('#guessList').text("<li>You'll need to go higher.</li>");
        } else if (guess > number) {
            $('#guessList').text("<li>"+"You'll need to go lower."+'</li>')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** See @Buzinas answer for your syntax error.

You are setting with `.text()` rather than `.html()`.

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML.

Your code will insert

```
<ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">
  &lt;li&gt;You'll need to go higher.&lt;/li&gt;
</ul>
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

You will overwrite the content each time so instead use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to keep adding your new elements e.g;

```
$('#guessList').append($("<li>You'll need to go higher.</li>"));
```

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked, big time newb mistake. Thanks for the help @Dave Anderson!!!

Answer (score 1):

1.You didn't define 'number' in js;

2.You should use `.val()` to get guess number;

3.The type of guess button shouldn't be submit;

4.Use `.html()` or `.append()` rather not `.text()`;

```
<input type="button" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
$("#guessButton").click(function() {
var number = 1;
var guess = $('#userGuess').val();
if (guess == number) {
$('#guessList').html("<li>You've guessed the number!!</li>");
} else if (guess < number) {
$('#guessList').html("<li>You'll need to go higher.</li>");
} else if (guess > number) {
$('#guessList').html("<li>" + "You'll need to go lower." + '</li>')
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
var guess = $('#userGuess').val;
```

When using jQuery, the way to set properties is by [using functions](http://api.jquery.com/val/). If you don't pass any parameter, it's a `get` function, and if you pass, then, it's a `set` one. So you should use:

```
var guess = $('#userGuess').val();
```